# Encoding of BrokeredMessage Body in Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, azure, encoding, azureservicebus

We have the below wrapper around the Azure Service Bus Client:

```
public virtual void SendMessage(object bodyObject)
{
    var brokeredMessage = 
        _messageBodySerializer.SerializeMessageBody(bodyObject);

    _queueClient.Send(brokeredMessage);
}
```

With the `SerializeMessageBody` consisting of:

```
public BrokeredMessage SerializeMessageBody(object bodyObject)
{
    var brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(bodyObject);

    brokeredMessage.Properties[MESSAGE_TYPE_PROPERTY_KEY] = 
                    bodyObject.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;

    return brokeredMessage;
}
```

I've written an integration test to check this works by running `SendMessage` then viewing the message contents using [Service Bus Explorer 2.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2013/04/12/service-bus-explorer-2-0-released.aspx).  We are doing this to ensure we can repair and resend messages using the tool to modify the XML.  The message I am sending looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestServiceBusMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ExternalIdentifier { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Identifier { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is; when the message body is viewed on the tool, instead of looking like XML it instead comes out like below:

```
@TestServiceBusMessageWhttp://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IntegrationTests.Common.Azure.ServiceBus   i)http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance@ExternalIdentifier?$13d81b90-d932-437f-a11c-9106412b6c4a@
Identifier?&    @Name?Test Message
```

I assume this is an encoding issue; however I cannot see a way to set the encoding when passing the body into the `BrokeredMessage` constructor; or defining it through a `DataContract` attribute.

How would I get around this encoding issue?  Would I need to provide my own [serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh330723.aspx) / [stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh330764.aspx) or is there a way to force the default serializer to encode correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try the following code. I tested it and I can see the payload in XML format using my tool (Service Bus Explorer: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a#content).
Basically, you need to explicitly specify the DataContractSerializer in the constructor of the BrokeredMessage object. Hope this helps.
Ciao
Paolo

```
#region MyRegion
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging; 
#endregion

namespace StackOverflow
{
    static class Program
    {
        #region Private Constants
        private const string QueueName = "stackoverflow";
        private const string MessageType = "MessageType";
        private const string AssemblyName = "AssemblyName";
        private const string ConnectionString = "<your-service-bus-namespace-connectionstring>"; 
        #endregion

        #region Static Methods
        static void Main()
        {
            SendMessage();
        }

        static async void SendMessage()
        {
            try
            {
                // Create NamespaceManager object
                var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);
                Console.WriteLine("NamespaceManager successfully created.");

                // Create test queue
                if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(QueueName))
                {
                    namespaceManager.CreateQueue(new QueueDescription(QueueName)
                    {
                        RequiresDuplicateDetection = false,
                        RequiresSession = false,
                        LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
                    });
                    Console.WriteLine("Queue successfully created.");
                }

                // Create MessagingFactory object
                var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);
                Console.WriteLine("MessagingFactory successfully created.");

                // Create MessageSender object
                var messageSender = await messagingFactory.CreateMessageSenderAsync(QueueName);
                Console.WriteLine("MessageSender successfully created.");

                // Create message payload
                var testServiceBusMessage = new TestServiceBusMessage
                {
                    ExternalIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Identifier = 1,
                    Name = "Babo"
                };

                // Create BrokeredMessage object
                using (var brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(testServiceBusMessage,
                                                                 new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TestServiceBusMessage)))
                {
                    Properties = {{MessageType, typeof(TestServiceBusMessage).FullName},
                                  {AssemblyName, typeof(TestServiceBusMessage).AssemblyQualifiedName}}
                })
                {
                    //Send message
                    messageSender.SendAsync(brokeredMessage).Wait();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Message successfully sent.");
                Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        } 
        #endregion
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class TestServiceBusMessage
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Guid ExternalIdentifier { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Identifier { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly; adding the `DataContractSerializer` instance in the constructor solves the encoding issue, thank you Paolo.  (PS: [Azure Service Bus Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2013/04/12/service-bus-explorer-2-0-released.aspx) is excellent)

Comment: Also I published a post on my blog that details the different ways in which you can encode/decode the message body when using different protocols/platforms to send and receive messages: http://abhishekrlal.com/2012/03/30/formatting-the-content-for-service-bus-messages/

Comment: Is there any workaround when the message is already sitting in DeadLetter queue? As in can I get SBE to show the message that was already sent, without modifying the sending mechanism. We have a problem that we can't resubmit the messages via the SBE. Seems like SBE can't resubmit the messages that were created when using just `new BrokeredMessage(body);`